# How to mount a ham?

Tags: equipment, ham

I bought a Serrano ham on sale. It's the whole pig's leg, and it comes with a kind of a stand. However, the stand was delivered in pieces like IKEA furniture, but unlike IKEA, it has no manual explaining what goes where.

I'm especially puzzled about the large ring and the small trapez-without-base shaped pieces. Once must go up to hold the ankle, the other one down to hold the haunch. But which goes where, and how do I fasten the ham to the metal? Do I have to screw the metal screws through the bone? 
[image]

The picture shows all parts delivered, only the inbus key is not in the frame. I put the trapezoid part onto the lower hole and started fastening it with a pointy screw; it's quite a long screw (7-8cm).

Comment: It kinda looks like you're supposed to mount the whole thing onto the wall (I don't see a hole for that though...), attach the ring to the arm, then stick the bone through the ring and let the weight of the ham make it stick in the ring. Any chance that'll work?

Comment: @Jefromi I'm pretty sure it's supposed to stay on the counter, not go onto the wall. I've seen it somewhere. There is also a picture on the outside of the package, and the stand is on a flat surface. Sadly, it shows a much more elaborate kind of stand with a different mounting system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help, it's not precisely exact, but you can probably figure it out from here.

[image: 1]

Comment: Yep. If you had bought Iberico (good God that is expensive) you would have an extra part or two :)

Answer (score 2):

OK, after some fitting of screws and so on, I think I managed to find the correct fit. Jolene's picture also helped.

The two pointy screws get indeed screwed into the ham, but there is enough flesh and sinew that I don't have to go into the bone with them. This is lucky, because getting a screw in when using only a tiny L-shaped "screwdriver" greased with pig fat is hard work even when it's sinking into soft material.

[image]

One thing not visible from the picture: The long pointy screw goes through the middle of the black trapezoidal holder straight into the haunch.

Comment: Looks about right, but are you sure you don't have the ham upside down?

Comment: @PeterTaylor there was a user guide about cutting the ham, which also described the ham position. As far as I understood it, the ham is supposed to be like that. But I'll look into it again when I'm home.

Comment: It depends on how fast you're going to use it, if you're intending on getting through it quickly the other way up is perhaps best. You end up cutting one side, then the other, either way. The slices you generally see packaged are from the big side. The hard bit is getting it really thin, if anyone has tips on that I'd be interested.

Comment: @vwiggins You can post the request for tips in a separate question, it will be a good question. Personally, I enjoy munching on a thick piece of ham, even though it goes against tradition and economic considerations.